# How to fill NA values in first row of the column on basis of another column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, na

I have a csv file where in one of the column i need to fill NA values on the basis of data which is available above in same column.For example lets say if lets say column data is like this `chrome,NA,NA,Explorer,NA` I want it to be `chrome,chrome,chrome,Explorer,Explorer` and i am able to achieve this but now i have another problem lets say the column data is like this `NA,NA,chrome,Explorer,NA` I get output as `NA,NA,chrome,Explorer,Explorer`(here NA in first row Output Section I want to replace by another column data in same row)

In order to fill missing values on the basis of data from same column i used this code-

> filling a missing value with previous ones

```
data["Application Name"].fillna(method ='pad', inplace = True)
data.iloc[:,4].fillna(method ='pad', inplace = True)
data.head()
```

Here is the Input csv Data-

```
Sequence Number Action Name Title   Recorder Type   Application Name
1   1   ANT Logger      
2   5       Chrome Recorder 
3   5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
4   5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
5   5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
6   6   xyz Chrome Recorder Chrome
7   7       Chrome Recorder Chrome
```

In the above example Apllication name in First row is missing and there even we can't use fillna because it is the first row of csv so i want to use title
data to be used in Apllication name column which basically means i want output like this-

```
Action Name Title   Recorder Type   Application Name
1   ANT Logger      ANT Logger
5       Chrome Recorder ANT Logger
5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
5       Chrome Recorder Chrome
6   xyz Chrome Recorder Chrome
7       Chrome Recorder Chrome
```

Comment: answers your question apparently (cross dupe?): https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/how-to-fill-missing-value-based-on-other-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/17770#17770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use backward and forward fill using rows:

```
df = df.ffill(axis ='rows').bfill(axis ='rows')
```

Comment: I don't want to backward or forward fill i want to know how to fill missing data in column on the basis of data from another column from same row...

Comment: here, axis='rows', means value in current na(missing value) cells are filled from the corresponding value in the next row or previous row of same column, you can use axis ='columns' to fill missing data using next or previous column data from same row